# Select nodes with specific attribute from a relation

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am trying to build subway maps using [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) and output in JSON. I only want the routes (ways) and the stations (nodes) for each network. This is what I have so far:

```
[out:json];
(
  relation["network"="NYC Subway"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

With this query, I not only get the station nodes, but also nodes for exits, platforms, etc. for each station. I only want the 'main' station node as shown in this picture:
[image: main_station_node]

These nodes have attributes `public_transport=station` and `railway=station` while the exits and platforms do not. I am having trouble filtering only these main station nodes in overpass. I have tried this:

```
[out:json];
(
  relation["network"="NYC Subway"];
  node(r)["railway"="station"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

However, this is still giving me nodes for exits, platforms, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1C00

```
/*
Get NYC Subway station nodes & Railway subway ways
*/

[out:json];

(
  // get subway nodes
  node["network"="NYC Subway"]["railway"="station"]({{bbox}});
  // get subway ways/'lines'
  way[railway=subway]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

[image: Subway Lines and Nodes in Overpass Turbo]

[image: 18th Street Results]